# HashMap returning false always for containsValue(),

Tags: java, hashmap

I am implementing a HashMap and it always returns false even if the character is repeating. I tried the solution that was given in other Stack Overflow problem, but didn't help, same is the case with Hashtable with function contains().

```
 HashMap<Character, Boolean> ht=new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(!ht.containsValue(new Character(s.charAt(i))))
            ht.put(new Character(s.charAt(i)),true);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: You are putting your characters into the map as keys, and then checking if they exist as values in the map - thats why its always false. Use ht.containsKey() instead of ht.containsValue

Comment: for your code, use ``containsKey()``

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks, that was a blunder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, use `containsKey()`

```
 HashMap<Character, Boolean> ht=new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(!ht.containsKey(new Character(s.charAt(i))))
            ht.put(new Character(s.charAt(i)),true);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```